# Google Rich Snippets Data - Sometimes working/showing in google search result and sometimes not

Tags: wordpress, schema.org, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I have been experiencing this problem with google rich snippets data for a while now, sometimes google will show the rich snippets I added to my Wordpress post (star ratings, thumbnail, review count, prep time etc), and sometimes it just wont ( with star ratings, review count, prep time etc, but thumbnail missing).

This happens randomly ( I think ) to post I posted recently ( which uses identical rich snippet markup structure ). ( Old posts, like over a year ago which was marked up recently usually wont experience this problem )

I cant figure out what is causing the problem, and re-fetching the URL ( Google Webmaster Tools ) with missing thumbnail wont last long ( the thumbnail will show temporarily, and gone missing again after a while )

This is a screenshot of a post displayed correctly in google search result:

[image: This is a screenshot of a post displayed correctly in google search result]

This is a screenshot of a post displayed incorrectly in google search result:
[image: This is a screenshot of a post displayed incorrectly in google search result:]

Both of these post have the same Rich Snippets Data structure. ( Can be checked/compared at https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ )

I hope someone can help me find out the cause of this problem

Comment: If the pages are the same, and they eventually start working, my guess would be that it's something to do with Google indexing/caching/cdn and unfortunately out of your control.

Comment: is there anything wrong my schema.org rich snippet? anyone can help me pls?